# android thread exiting with uncaught exception in Bluetooth data reading function

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am using below code to read data from external h/w. device but the application crashes with exception.***Thread exiting with uncaught exception***

Here is my code for reading data via external device:

```
 private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private InputStream mmInStream;
            private OutputStream mmOutStream;
            private InputStream mByteQueue;
            private byte[] mReceiveBuffer;
            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
                mmSocket = socket;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;
                // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
                }
                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }
            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        // Read from the InputStream
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                        sb.append(bytesToHex(buffer));
                    }

catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    testModeOnScreen.sendMailTest("ricky.khatri@techvalens.com","Received bytes"+e.toString(),"IOEXCEPTION");//mahmoud.elsabrouty@eid-solutions.com
                    connectionLost();
                    //break;
                }
                 }
             }
 }
```

This code is to call the thread:

```
mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
try {
            mConnectedThread.join();

testModeOnScreen.sendMailTest("ricky.khatri@techvalens.com","Raw Data:===>"+sb.toString(),"RECEIVED DATA IN HEX STRING"+buffer.length);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is logcat:

```
D/BluetoothReadService(21039): connect to: 00:06:66:45:DE:6E
D/BluetoothReadService(21039): setState() 0 -> 2
I/BluetoothReadService(21039): BEGIN mConnectThread
E/BluetoothService.cpp(  234): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 54% free 3130K/6791K, external 841K/1036K, paused 1ms+2ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:06:66:45:DE:6E)
D/BluetoothService(  234):  uuid(application): 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1
D/BluetoothService(  234): Making callback for 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb with result 1
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): new handle 10008
D/BluetoothReadService(21039): connected
D/BluetoothReadService(21039): create ConnectedThread
I/BluetoothReadService(21039): BEGIN mConnectedThread
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 58K, 48% free 2798K/5379K, external 1487K/1741K, paused 3ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 48% free 2809K/5379K, external 3814K/4496K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 48% free 2817K/5379K, external 5255K/5782K, paused 4ms+8ms
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 48% free 2826K/5379K, external 6708K/7223K, paused 1ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 48% free 2847K/5379K, external 7287K/9064K, paused 2ms+1ms
I/Ads     (21052): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C");
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.abworkouts/.AbWorkoutsActivity: +1s272ms
I/Ads     (21052): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1,"slotname":"a14e2a1804aace4","u_w":320,"msid":"com.abworkouts","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C","format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"2.android.com.abworkouts","hl":"en","u_h":480,"u_audio":3,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
I/Ads     (21052): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=0&u_sd=1&u_w=320&msid=com.abworkouts&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=2.android.com.abworkouts&hl=en&u_h=480&u_audio=3&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-120&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14e2a1804aace4&caps=sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=255
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cyttsp_key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65539.devname='cyttsp_key'
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  234): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1435K, 35% free 8104K/12423K, external 1865K/2102K, paused 6ms+29ms
W/webcore (21052): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
I/Ads     (21052): onReceiveAd()
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 55% free 3113K/6791K, external 848K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(20671): GC_EXPLICIT freed 156K, 49% free 2781K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 90ms
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
D/kernel  (  126): [113741.460449] bq27520 0-0055: bq27520_handle_soc_worker() capacity=90 (90) flags=0x128 ctrl_status=0x28b soh_state=0x3, valid=1
D/lights  (  234): set_light_battery: color=0xff00ff00, mode=0
W/dalvikvm(21039): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
E/JavaBinder(  234): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/kernel  (  126): [113743.098999] binder: 20149: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
D/kernel  (  126): [113743.098999] binder: 234:8767 transaction failed 29201, size 228-4
E/JavaBinder(  234): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/kernel  (  126): [113743.099426] binder: 20149: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
D/kernel  (  126): [113743.099426] binder: 234:8767 transaction failed 29201, size 88-4
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  117): GC_EXPLICIT freed 11K, 49% free 2762K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 167ms
D/dalvikvm(20796): GC_EXPLICIT freed 283K, 50% free 3033K/5959K, external 743K/1036K, paused 134ms
D/dalvikvm(  117): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 49% free 2762K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 53ms
D/dalvikvm(  117): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 49% free 2762K/5379K, external 743K/1036K, paused 37ms
D/dalvikvm(21091): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.sonyericsson.android.bootinfo/lib/libMiscTaAccessor.so 0x2afc6210
D/dalvikvm(21091): Added shared lib /data/data/com.sonyericsson.android.bootinfo/lib/libMiscTaAccessor.so 0x2afc6210
I/Process (21039): Sending signal. PID: 21039 SIG: 9
E/kernel  (  126): [113748.968505] binder: release proc 21039, transaction 1176367, not freed
W/GpsLocationProvider(  234): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
D/kernel  (  126): [113749.117797] binder: 330:330 transaction failed 29189, size 88-0
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 54% free 3133K/6791K, external 841K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
D/dalvikvm(20611): GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 47% free 3173K/5959K, external 747K/1036K, paused 2ms+11ms
D/dalvikvm(21101): GC_CONCURRENT freed 320K, 49% free 2964K/5703K, external 1358K/1870K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 730K, 53% free 3323K/6983K, external 1876K/2388K, paused 1ms+6ms
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.SplashScreen: +344ms
D/dalvikvm(21101): GC_CONCURRENT freed 10K, 48% free 2977K/5703K, external 2048K/2470K, paused 6ms+2ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.HomeScreen: +431ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 410K, 55% free 3108K/6791K, external 848K/1036K, paused 1ms+2ms
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.ApplicationTabActivity: +378ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(21101): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 45% free 3178K/5767K, external 2491K/3111K, paused 2ms+14ms
I/iddd-events(  124): Event com.sonyericsson.idd.probe.android.network::CellLocationChanged was discarded since it was not active.
W/GpsLocationProvider(  234): Duplicate add listener for uid 10152
D/PhoneWindow(21101): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2b025280 has no id.
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>Starting Discovery
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.bluetooth.SearchDeviceActivity: +251ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(94:39:E5:E1:99:52)
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>showDevices
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:06:66:45:DE:6E)
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>showDevices
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(68:EB:AE:7B:78:AB)
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>showDevices
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(50:2D:1D:57:40:AD)
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>showDevices
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 410K, 54% free 3130K/6791K, external 841K/1036K, paused 1ms+3ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>unregisterReceiver
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>Finished
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_EXPLICIT freed 232K, 55% free 3083K/6791K, external 813K/1036K, paused 106ms
D/EF-BTBee(21101): >>Click device
D/BluetoothReadService(21101): connect to: 00:06:66:45:DE:6E
D/BluetoothReadService(21101): setState() 0 -> 2
I/BluetoothReadService(21101): BEGIN mConnectThread
E/BluetoothService.cpp(  234): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:06:66:45:DE:6E)
D/BluetoothService(  234):  uuid(application): 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1
D/BluetoothService(  234): Making callback for 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb with result 1
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 545K, 49% free 3087K/6023K, external 9288K/11336K, paused 3ms+9ms
D/webviewglue(21052): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a74a0
D/webviewglue(21052): nativeDestroy view: 0x2b06a0
D/BluetoothReadService(21101): connected
D/BluetoothReadService(21101): create ConnectedThread
I/BluetoothReadService(21101): BEGIN mConnectedThread
D/dalvikvm(21052): GC_CONCURRENT freed 40K, 50% free 3071K/6023K, external 11798K/13846K, paused 1ms+5ms
W/kernel  (  126): [113785.020996] select 19978 (wsandroid.suite), adj 10, size 3510, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113785.021026] select 20846 (ackageinstaller), adj 10, size 4643, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113785.021057] send sigkill to 20846 (ackageinstaller), adj 10, size 4643
I/Ads     (21052): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C");
I/Ads     (21052): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"u_sd":1,"slotname":"a14e2a1804aace4","u_w":320,"msid":"com.abworkouts","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C","format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"2.android.com.abworkouts","hl":"en","u_h":480,"u_audio":3,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.abworkouts/.AbWorkoutsActivity: +1s9ms
I/Ads     (21052): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=1&u_sd=1&u_w=320&msid=com.abworkouts&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=2.android.com.abworkouts&hl=en&u_h=480&u_audio=3&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-120&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14e2a1804aace4&askip=1&caps=sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=255
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cyttsp_key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65539.devname='cyttsp_key'
W/KeyCharacterMap(21052): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 739K, 53% free 3321K/6983K, external 1876K/2388K, paused 1ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 343K, 54% free 3128K/6791K, external 820K/1036K, paused 4ms+2ms
W/webcore (21052): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
I/Ads     (21052): onReceiveAd()
W/dalvikvm(21101): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
I/Process (  234): Sending signal. PID: 21101 SIG: 9
W/GpsLocationProvider(  234): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
E/kernel  (  126): [113791.191711] binder: release proc 21101, transaction 1177884, not freed
E/kernel  (  126): [113791.191711] binder: release proc 21101, transaction 1177885, not freed
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 55% free 3117K/6791K, external 869K/1036K, paused 1ms+2ms
I/InputDispatcher(  234): Dropped event because of pending overdue app switch.
I/InputDispatcher(  234): Dropped event because of pending overdue app switch.
I/InputDispatcher(  234): Dropped event because of pending overdue app switch.
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=255
D/kernel  (  126): [113804.855285] binder: 330:330 transaction failed 29189, size 88-0
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
W/KeyCharacterMap(  407): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(  407): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cyttsp_key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65539.devname='cyttsp_key'
W/KeyCharacterMap(  407): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 54% free 3154K/6791K, external 847K/1036K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(21118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 54K, 48% free 2800K/5379K, external 1343K/1855K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.SplashScreen: +372ms
D/dalvikvm(21118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 48% free 2817K/5379K, external 2033K/2455K, paused 5ms+2ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.HomeScreen: +411ms
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 55% free 3119K/6791K, external 869K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(19978): GC_EXPLICIT freed 21K, 48% free 2914K/5511K, external 743K/1036K, paused 97ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(21118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 363K, 48% free 3117K/5895K, external 2254K/2455K, paused 2ms+2ms
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.ApplicationTabActivity: +371ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  234): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1059K, 36% free 8037K/12423K, external 2123K/2652K, paused 4ms+16ms
I/iddd-events(  124): Event com.sonyericsson.idd.probe.android.network::CellLocationChanged was discarded since it was not active.
W/GpsLocationProvider(  234): Duplicate add listener for uid 10152
D/PhoneWindow(21118): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afd9510 has no id.
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>Starting Discovery
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0
W/kernel  (  126): [113825.539550] select 19978 (wsandroid.suite), adj 10, size 3550, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113825.539550] select 20868 (id.defcontainer), adj 10, size 3706, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113825.539581] send sigkill to 20868 (id.defcontainer), adj 10, size 3706
W/kernel  (  126): [113825.639282] select 19978 (wsandroid.suite), adj 10, size 3550, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113825.639312] send sigkill to 19978 (wsandroid.suite), adj 10, size 3550
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.empowereddefence/.bluetooth.SearchDeviceActivity: +266ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(68:EB:AE:7B:78:AB)
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(94:39:E5:E1:99:52)
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>showDevices
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>showDevices
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:06:66:45:DE:6E)
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>showDevices
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 401K, 55% free 3122K/6791K, external 847K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceFound from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(50:2D:1D:57:40:AD)
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>showDevices
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>unregisterReceiver
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>Finished
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 732K, 53% free 3324K/6983K, external 1876K/2388K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm(18376): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2081K, 37% free 8755K/13895K, external 1108K/1620K, paused 14ms+7ms
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 420K, 55% free 3119K/6791K, external 869K/1036K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/EF-BTBee(21118): >>Click device
D/BluetoothReadService(21118): connect to: 00:06:66:45:DE:6E
D/BluetoothReadService(21118): setState() 0 -> 2
I/BluetoothReadService(21118): BEGIN mConnectThread
E/BluetoothService.cpp(  234): stopDiscoveryNative: D-Bus error in StopDiscovery: org.bluez.Error.Failed (Invalid discovery session)
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
D/BluetoothService(  234): updateDeviceServiceChannelCache(00:06:66:45:DE:6E)
D/BluetoothService(  234):  uuid(application): 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 1
D/BluetoothService(  234): Making callback for 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb with result 1
D/dalvikvm(20611): GC_CONCURRENT freed 333K, 46% free 3339K/6087K, external 747K/1036K, paused 8ms+42ms
I/Ads     (21052): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C");
I/Ads     (21052): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":2,"u_sd":1,"slotname":"a14e2a1804aace4","u_w":320,"msid":"com.abworkouts","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C","format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"2.android.com.abworkouts","hl":"en","u_h":480,"u_audio":3,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed com.abworkouts/.AbWorkoutsActivity: +338ms
D/BluetoothReadService(21118): connected
D/BluetoothReadService(21118): create ConnectedThread
I/BluetoothReadService(21118): BEGIN mConnectedThread
I/Ads     (21052): Received ad url: <"url": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=2&u_sd=1&u_w=320&msid=com.abworkouts&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=A8B81027D5AFA70ABB40D69832B8A12C&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=2.android.com.abworkouts&hl=en&u_h=480&u_audio=3&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=-120&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14e2a1804aace4&askip=2&caps=sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=41", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=255
W/webcore (21052): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
I/Ads     (21052): onReceiveAd()
D/dalvikvm(18376): GC_EXPLICIT freed 749K, 38% free 8619K/13895K, external 1108K/1620K, paused 185ms
W/dalvikvm(21118): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
W/kernel  (  126): [113851.539062] select 20796 (son.eventstream), adj 9, size 4715, to kill
W/kernel  (  126): [113851.539093] send sigkill to 20796 (son.eventstream), adj 9, size 4715
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 372K, 54% free 3154K/6791K, external 847K/1036K, paused 1ms+3ms
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
I/Process (21118): Sending signal. PID: 21118 SIG: 9
E/JavaBinder(  234): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
W/GpsLocationProvider(  234): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000
E/kernel  (  126): [113854.632080] binder: 21118: binder_alloc_buf, no vma
D/kernel  (  126): [113854.632141] binder: 234:273 transaction failed 29201, size 60-0
D/kernel  (  126): [113854.634613] binder: 234:9603 transaction failed 29189, size 56-0
E/InputDispatcher(  234): channel '2b565930 com.empowereddefence/com.empowereddefence.ApplicationTabActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(  234): channel '2b565930 com.empowereddefence/com.empowereddefence.ApplicationTabActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/kernel  (  126): [113854.831542] binder: 330:330 transaction failed 29189, size 88-0
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  407): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1952K, 53% free 4159K/8711K, external 5958K/6629K, paused 2ms+23ms
E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(  234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Device:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/370/hci0/dev_00_06_66_45_DE_6E
V/alogcat (21025): created
D/alogcat (21025): canceling periodic saves
V/alogcat (21025): started
V/alogcat (21025): resumed
D/alogcat (21025): starting ...
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(21025): GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 49% free 3006K/5831K, external 1166K/1678K, paused 2ms+12ms
I/ActivityManager(  234): Displayed org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity: +348ms
D/CustomizationProvider(20671): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp
D/dalvikvm(  330): GC_CONCURRENT freed 743K, 53% free 3316K/6983K, external 1876K/2388K, paused 2ms+11ms
D/lights  (  234): set_light_buttons: brightness=255
W/KeyCharacterMap(21025): Can't open keycharmap file
W/KeyCharacterMap(21025): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cyttsp_key.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65539.devname='cyttsp_key'
W/KeyCharacterMap(21025): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/dalvikvm(20213): GC_CONCURRENT freed 448K, 55% free 3119K/6791K, external 869K/1036K, paused 1ms+3ms
```

Comment: Can you please add the logcat output?

Comment: No catch method inside run for try block what I can observe initially. Apart from that posting logcat will also assist others to help you.

Comment: @Henry I have posted my logcat.

Comment: @BlackDevil Sorry i just forgot to post the whole code.Please see the code again.

Comment: Can anyone answer the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, GC_CONCURRENT it's a Garbage Collector, i think it's happens because you try to send a lot of big size data to device in a short period of time and device thinks is a flood, i put " Thread.sleep(5) " after every 5 transactions for me it works.